# phyton3 access list column with selected range

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I am newbee on python programming language  and I have a problem about accessing list items like this.

My data is `data=[[664159, 550946, 1, 1],[665845, 557965, 1, 2],[597173, 575538, 1, 3],[635690, 608046, 1, 5]]`

I want to access first two colums of first items that is `[664159, 550946]` and I am try to this 
`>data[0][0:1]` 
but i get only first colums data that is `[664159]` result. I havent got any idea for solving it. Can you help me please? What is my wrong?

`>data=[[664159, 550946, 1, 1],[665845, 557965, 1, 2],[597173, 575538, 1, 3],[635690, 608046, 1, 5]]`

`>data[0][0:1]`

`>>[664159]`

Comment: You want the first two columns? `data[0][0:2]` ? The end of a slice is exclusive, so `0:1` is just the first... while `0:2` gives you up to but not including, so it's the first and second, and so on...

Comment: thank you jon it solved my problem